# What rule determines escaping in JSON

Tags: json, string, escaping

Say I have this:

```
const v = {
  val: ' bad \\"  string"'
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(v));
```

JSON.stringify knows to add an escape \ backslash so that the output looks like:

```
{"val":" bad \\\"  string\""}
```

what rule is being followed here? How does the stringify routine know to add the 3rd backslash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what rule is being followed here? How does the stringify routine know to add the 3rd backslash?

This JavaScript string literal

```
' bad \\"  string"'
```

represents this string

```
 bad \"  string"
```

when converted to JSON, the double quotes `"` and the backslashes `\` must be escaped, so

```
" bad \\\"  string\""
```

follows naturally. Straight from [json.org](http://json.org/):

[image: JSON string syntax diagram]

Comment: So  `\\"` becomes `\\\"` because the first backslash needs to be escaped, and the second backslash is interpreted as modifying the `"`?

Comment: Exactly. It's easier when you picture in your mind the actual, in-memory string before applying the JSON escaping rules. Trying to figure out where to add backslashes to the JS string literal is needlessly complicated - and it's not what is really happening, either - the JS interpreter unescapes the string literal before it uses it, after all.

Comment: I am looking for a simple rule in English like "when transforming to JSON, a backslash needs to be added before another backslash X unless X precedes an n, t, r, ", etc.

Comment: As I said, that's not a good way to go about it. You need to understand what the string looks like in reality, this means you need to unescape the JS string literal in your mind. And *then* you can effortlessly escape it again with JSON rules.

Comment: Yeah so I guess you have to assume it's either already unescaped or already escaped before proceeding

Comment: It **is** unescaped. The escaped form only exists in the JS source code. As soon as the JS parser has read it in, it is unescaped. The problem *"where to add backslashes to the ones that are already there"* is never being solved in the real world.